# How to configure post buffer size in GIT from Netbeans IDE globally which uses Bitbucket?

Tags: git, netbeans, bitbucket, netbeans-15

I got this 500 server error when push to Git and pull from Git, I found out that one of the solutions is to increase post buffer size and I want to know how it be done without using command line?
Relevant code:
`git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In apache netbeans 15 from navigation panel you must navigate to

- Team -> Git -> Open Global Configuration
  Then it will open `.gitconfig` file for global configuration.
  You just need to add following code

```
[http]
    postBuffer = 1048576000
```